# AWS: what action in policy for making Lambda write to Aurora?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

I need to create a IAM role a Lambda can assume to perform an insert statement to an Aurora RDS...still in the RDS actions nothing appears to correspond to read/write access.
How to control that access???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not manage this kind of permission via IAM.
IAM permissions related to Amazon RDS are about **the management of RDS itself**: [management of instances, cluster, snapshots etc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAM.AccessControl.Overview.html)...

The authorization to perform an insert statement is defined for your database user. As [Amazon Aurora is designed to be compatible with MySQL 5.6](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/details/), you should manage user permissions [like you would do with MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).